# Ember.js: Pass options to node.js

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I'm trying to build some LESS code (via ember-cli-less) to CSS file.

1) https://almsaeedstudio.com/ AdminLTE LESS files
2) Bootstrap LESS files.

And I got:

```
⠸ Building
<--- Last few GCs --->
87632 ms: Scavenge 1403.1 (1458.1) -> 1403.1 (1458.1) MB, 92.0 / 0 ms (+ 19.3 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
90306 ms: Mark-sweep 1403.1 (1458.1) -> 1399.0 (1457.1) MB, 2674.4 / 0 ms (+ 1196.1 ms in 2698 steps since start of marking, biggest step 21.2 ms) [last resort gc].
93043 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.0 (1457.1) -> 1396.1 (1458.1) MB, 2737.2 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x26d2e65b4629 <JS Object>
1: eval [/home/ofry/my-new-lk/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/ruleset.js:~33] [pc=0x2f428a9933db] (this=0x26d2e6581591 <JS Object>,context=0x289d4931c589 <JS Object>)
2: eval [/home/ofry/my-new-lk/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/ruleset.js:~33] [pc=0x2f428a992d84] (this=0x289d4931c7a1 <JS Object>,context=0x289d4931c589 <JS Object>)
3: evalCall [/home/ofry/my-new-lk/node_modules/less...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

So I need to pass somehow --max_old_space_size=big_number when launch

```
ember build
```

How I can do this?

UPDATE:
Tried to use:

```
lessOptions: {
paths: [
'app/styles/less',
'bower_components/bootstrap/less'
],
max_old_space_size: 8192
},
```

Same error:

```
⠧ Building
<--- Last few GCs --->

216135 ms: Scavenge 1401.6 (1458.1) -> 1401.6 (1458.1) MB, 78.7 / 0 ms (+ 3.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
218646 ms: Mark-sweep 1401.6 (1458.1) -> 1401.2 (1458.1) MB, 2510.4 / 0 ms (+ 4.0 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 3.0 ms) [last resort gc].
221062 ms: Mark-sweep 1401.2 (1458.1) -> 1400.3 (1458.1) MB, 2415.8 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x62f3f2b4629 <JS Object>
1: eval [/home/ofry/my-new-lk/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/ruleset.js:~33] [pc=0x3f6eb137cc4f] (this=0x25d46c7e8bd9 <JS Object>,context=0xe80f72a7819 <JS Object>)
2: eval [/home/ofry/my-new-lk/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/ruleset.js:~33] [pc=0x3f6eb137ed67] (this=0xe80f72a7a31 <JS Object>,context=0xe80f72a7819 <JS Object>)
3: evalCall [/home/ofry/my-new-lk/node_modules/less/lib...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Update #2.
Link to repo with example:
https://github.com/ofry/test_ember_cli_less

Comment: did you try just add 'max_old_space_size' into lessOptions ?

Comment: Tried to use: 'lessOptions: {
      paths: [
        'app/styles/less',
        'bower_components/bootstrap/less'
      ],
      max_old_space_size: 8192
    },'.

Comment: is your repo public? can you share link?

Comment: no, it's not public. But now it's only sample code. So I can share it :) 1 minute please.

Comment: ember-cli-less use brocolli-less-single which use less.js . And I didn't find how to pass option using less.js. Did you? ( I found only max_line_len at https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/bin/lessc )

Comment: right now I can only propose monkeypatching for file lessc ( in postInstall section for example ) but it's ugly ((

Comment: Oh. I see. It's v8 option,not less )

Comment: Could you make pull request with this code? This repo is public :) So you can clone it and make pull request :)

Comment: Thank you. You really help me :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your first question is

```
 node --max_old_space_size=999999 ./node_modules/.bin/ember build
```

Run command from root of your project. Here we manually run node with ember script and pass all needed params ( node options first, script (ember) script options )

But for your repo ( ofry/test_ember_cli_less )I got another error ( which is related to your less code )

```
⠙ BuildingSyntaxError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in bower_components/bootstrap/less/grid.less on line 56, column 1:
55 
56 .make-grid(xs);
57 

Build failed.
File: bower_components/bootstrap/less/grid.less (56)
The Broccoli Plugin: [LessCompiler] failed with:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at MixinCall.eval (/Users/vvs/repo/test_ember_cli_less/node_modules/ember-cli-less/node_modules/broccoli-less-single/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/mixin-call.js:136:46)
    at Ruleset.eval (/Users/vvs/repo/test_ember_cli_less/node_modules/ember-cli-less/node_modules/broccoli-less-single/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/ruleset.js:116:32)
    at module.exports (/Users/vvs/repo/test_ember_cli_less/node_modules/ember-cli-less/node_modules/broccoli-less-single/node_modules/less/lib/less/transform-tree.js:67:22)
    at ParseTree.toCSS (/Users/vvs/repo/test_ember_cli_less/node_modules/ember-cli-less/node_modules/broccoli-less-single/node_modules/less/lib/less/parse-tree.js:14:25)
    at /Users/vvs/repo/test_ember_cli_less/node_modules/ember-cli-less/node_modules/broccoli-less-single/node_modules/less/lib/less/render.js:31:40
    at /Users/vvs/repo/test_ember_cli_less/node_modules/ember-cli-less/node_modules/broccoli-less-single/node_modules/less/lib/less/parse.js:63:17
    at Object.finish [as _finish] (/Users/vvs/repo/test_ember_cli_less/node_modules/ember-cli-less/node_modules/broccoli-less-single/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser/parser.js:183:28)
    at Object.ImportVisitor._onSequencerEmpty (/Users/vvs/repo/test_ember_cli_less/node_modules/ember-cli-less/node_modules/broccoli-less-single/node_modules/less/lib/less/visitors/import-visitor.js:35:14)
    at ImportSequencer.tryRun (/Users/vvs/repo/test_ember_cli_less/node_modules/ember-cli-less/node_modules/broccoli-less-single/node_modules/less/lib/less/visitors/import-sequencer.js:50:14)
    at /Users/vvs/repo/test_ember_cli_less/node_modules/ember-cli-less/node_modules/broccoli-less-single/node_modules/less/lib/less/visitors/import-sequencer.js:19:25
```

Related [issue is here](https://github.com/ofry/test_ember_cli_less/issues/1)

And there is no need to copy bootstrap sources into your app/styles directory - use bower/npm